# unit testing with sails.js using sequelize.js

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, sails.js, sequelize.js, waterline

I wrote the some [unit test in sails](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/testing) with waterline(defaultI  orm) That's working fine, but when I tried with sequelize orm I'm getting the error.
I'm using the following:

1. sequelize orm
2. sails-sequelize-hook
3. mocha and chai
4. supertest
5. "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2"
6. "pg": "^4.4.1"

My Folder structure is:

> ```
>   ./myApp
>     ├── api
>     ├── assets
>     ├── ...
>     ├── test
>     │  ├── unit
>     │  │  ├── controllers
>     │  │  │  └── UsersController.test.js
>     │  │  ├── models
>     │  │  │  └── Users.test.js
>     │  │  └── ...
>     │  ├── fixtures
>     │  ├── ...
>     │  ├── bootstrap.test.js
>     │  └── mocha.opts
>     └── views
> ```

my bootstrap.test.js file is:

```
  var Sails = require('sails'),sails;
  before(function(done) {
    this.timeout(5000);
    Sails.lift({
    }, function(err, server) {
      sails = server;
      if (err) return done(err);
      done(err, sails);
    });
  });
  after(function(done) {
    Sails.lower(done);
  });
```

my connection/config file is:

```
    somePostgresqlServer: {
      user: 'postgres',
      password: 'mypassword',
      database: 'postgres',
      dialect: 'postgres',
      options: {
          dialect: 'postgres',
          host   : 'localhost',
          port   : 5432,
          logging: true
      }
    }
```

and in config/model.js file is:

```
  connection:"somePostgresqlServer"
```

and my .sailsrc is :

```
  "hooks": {
      "blueprints": false,
      "orm": false,
      "pubsub": false
    }
```

I wrote some test in User.test.js 
when I'm running the mocha test/bootstrap.test.js test/unit/**/*.test.js

I'm getting the error:

```
  error: In model (user), invalid connection :: { user: 'postgres',
    password: 'mypassword',
    database: 'postgres',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    options: 
     { dialect: 'postgres',
       host: 'localhost',
       port: 5432,
       logging: [Function: _writeLogToConsole] } }
  error: Must contain an `adapter` key referencing the adapter to use.
  npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

what I'm doing the wrong any Idea.

Comment: Did you disabled the *orm* and *pubsub* hooks in `.sailsrc` has shown [here](https://github.com/festo/sails-hook-sequelize#user-content-configuration)?

Comment: Yes I did that. @AlexisN-o

Comment: The unit testing working fine without sequelize.js (with wateline), but when I'm using the sequelize the I'm getting the error.

Answer (score 2):

Alexis N-o's question is actually a good hint.

if you have a look in app.js (the one sails generated). It will load rc before trying to lift :) So just add the same code in your test bootstrap js will fix it.

```
    var rc;
    try {
        rc = require('rc');
    } catch (e0) {
    try {
      rc = require('sails/node_modules/rc');
    } catch (e1) {
      console.error('Could not find dependency: `rc`.');
      console.error('Your `.sailsrc` file(s) will be ignored.');
      console.error('To resolve this, run:');
      console.error('npm install rc --save');
      rc = function () { return {}; };
    }
  }
  // Start server
  sails.lift(rc('sails'));
```

Comment: How do I provide extra options like log with sails lift in this case?

Comment: Haven't tried. The first argument is options. U could try to add ur option to the first parameter